# Sorting a list of items based on categories (Android)

Tags: android, list, sorting

This isn't a specific Android problem/question, really, except that I'd like a nested/expandable list in an Activity.

I'm struggling a bit with how to solve this particular problem:
I want to display a list of items based on category, in a list (perhaps an nested/expanding list). The items are grouped in categories, and are received from a database query.

Here's a description of the database tables:

```
Table Categories
-----------------
CatID   CatName
01      Category1
02      Category2
03     Category3

Table Items
---------------------------------
ItemID  ItemName  Category
01      Item1     01
02      Item2     01
03      Item3     02
04      Item4     02
05      Item5     03
06      Item6     03
```

Example query result:

```
Category1   Item1
Category1   Item2
Category2   Item3
Category2   Item4
Category3   Item5
Category3   Item6
```

Now, what I'm wondering about is how to sort the items by category, and list them. In the Android GUI I'd like it to look something like this:

```
Category1
- Item1
- Item2
Category2
- Item3
- Item4
Category3
- Item5
- Item6
```

What's a good way to accomplis this, without messing around with a bunch of if's to check if an item belongs to this or that category, loop through all
the listed categories to avoid duplicate categories etc.? Or is there no good/tidy/standarized way of doing this?

Comment: so you have problem in only Listing those items or quering from database is an issue too?

Comment: The query is no problem. It's how I'm going to list/sort them in the Android view I'm wondering about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to go with ExpandableListView here. Create two seprate getter-setter classes one as Group and another as Child. Create ArrayList of Group and Child to set the data.

```
public class ExpandListGroup {

    private String Name;
    private ArrayList<ExpandListChild> childItems;

    public ArrayList<ExpandListChild> getChildItems() {
        return childItems;
    }
    public void setChildItems(ArrayList<ExpandListChild> childItems) {
        this.childItems = childItems;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}


public class ExpandListChild {

    private String Name;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }
}
```

Now you have to add Group and Child to an ArrayList and set the data of Group and Child to ExpandableList.

```
private ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> groups = new ArrayList<ExpandListGroup>();
private ArrayList<ExpandListChild> childs;
```

get the data in a cursor and set it to setter-getter classes like,

```
while(...){
 Group -> Category1, Category2, Category3,...
 Child -> Item1, Item2,....
}
```

Now you have your ArrayList of Group filled with its value and childs. Just set it to ExpandableList Adapter and you can work around it. For further clarification you can find [`here`](https://github.com/lalit3686/ExandableListViewDemo) is how you can fill the ExpandableList with Group and Child class.